# Which is faster, plain HTML or stored HTML from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic, content-management-system

I was wondering if it was faster if you had all your html in plain-text html file or in a PHP file which will load your html from database.

In case one the client will ask the page which will be sent immediately without the need for database interaction. In case two PHP has to load data from database and then convert them to objects and then it will be filled in the html file and that will be sent back to the host.

It looks like the first option is the fastest option. Mention that in both cases the dynamic HTML will be generated by PHP, which is also loaded through the database.

I am making a testing environment where I can test this. I will test this myself and I will upload results when I have them.

As far as I know Joomla loads the entire HTML document from database. Now when I want to make a CMS myself I want my webpages to load fast. In my opinion Joomla sucks and so my question remains:

Which is faster plain html or stored html from database?

I see that my question is generating a lot of emotions. I will add some more value to my question.

1. Am I testing this myself:"Yes of-course, I am not a lazy basted which is not prepared to seek for answers myself"
2. Then why are you asking:"I am interested in you opinion. It would be stupid to think that I can find all the answers by myself. Also there are a lot of programmers with the experience to know this so why don't ask"
3. In all cases the HTML is managed by a CMS. The idea is that the cms has to be fast in a really hybrid way. So it does not matter if you have a small website or a big website, if you have a website with actual dynamic contents or content which will be the same for a couple of years.
4. I see that in the comments people say that there is no performance issue or that it is so small it does not count. My question is:"Does it really not matter? Plain-text file or generating form database"
5. Caching? Ok, I will take a look into caching.

I have done some testing and this are the results. To me they occur strange and I can't make sense of it. I have used google chrome to store webpages of geensteil, tweakers.nl and stackoverflow (this page), google.com. Then I inspect the page with chromes inspect-tools and use the network button to see what I am loading. Then I copy the HTML and I put it into mysql myisam and I load it with PHP. I wrote down the results inside an excel file.

These are my testing results:

[image: here]

Comment: "*I am making a testing environment where I can test this. I will test this myself and I will upload results when I have them.*" - won't your results answer this question?

Comment: Which is easier for maintenance? Should you really store markup with content? Is Joomla the only CMS that has ever been written, or are there alternatives? If you're simply storing markup files, is there any value in having a CMS?

Comment: Stop [prematurely optimizing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Any speed difference is unlikely to be significant.

Comment: Is there any chance you'll have more than one web servers in the future that use the same database? And if so, will you need to update the HTML quickly and avoid inconsistencies between what is served by the servers? That's the only valid use case for storing HTML in the database I can imagine.

Comment: And if you really care about performance, maybe you shou8ld consider caching.  In front of either a DB or flat files.

Comment: If your boss want to change a CSS, you'll kill yourself if you store html in a database. Data and view are distinct things. Use caching tools, then store only data on the base, then create your views once when required. If you need some changes, you'll just need to clean the cache.

Comment: well if you load html from database, it will be pain in your butt if your client require to change css and designs, I can tell this much now. But my wild guess is that, loading from flat html file wont be the performance issue. You even have a plus point of being able to edit css and design easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly:

**Databases** - It takes time to do the handshaking between the server and the database plus the scripting ie. connect, query, return results, render results to page via script.

Whereas

**Flat file** - You're accessing the file directly so it'd be as if it was already embedded in a page, the only time would be to execute the code.

However, unless you're on a seriously slow and perhaps shared server you shouldn't really notice the difference. Joomla, is quite a demanding CMS in my opinion an it's not that great if you just want to put up a few pages. If you're after something simple, try reading a few tutorials and coding one yourself. This should get you started

1. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/creating-your-own-cms-1/
2. http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/

Comment: "It takes time to do the handshaking between the server and the database" — Not so, [PHP supports persistent database connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php)

Comment: This does not answer my question: "witch is the fasted way". My question was not how to make A CMS. Regarding that this knowledge is important if it comes to make a CMS. Also I am interested how other people or more likely programmers think about speed in this case. I am busy with my own research and it would be nice if someone with experience or testing results could give me some good answers. My only question is what is faster and in case of dynamic pages what is the best option.

Comment: @Quentin - True, however working on the assumption that you'd make and close each connection.

Comment: @sirwilliam - Apologies for not being clear, Technically a flat file however negligibly. There shouldn't be a noticeable difference though.

Comment: I've been testing and the results are really strange. I will upload my results any minute.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly considering the page load time of two identical HTML files (one served from filesystem and the other served from the DB) always the static file is the fastest.

You can serve it from for example Nginx, Varnish which are usually faster than apache. You don't need to load additional libraries like PHP, don't need to have the connection overhead to MySQL and then don't need to wait the query time.

*Note: PHP with Apache and mod_php has a significant overhead. Using persistent connection to MySQL or connection pooling, php-fpm instead of mod_php and APC can help a lot but it will be still very far from the speed of serving static files.*

If you want really fast page load time. Try nginx + memcache ( http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcachedModule ). Nginx has the ability to directly get the data from memcache. Put your whole html in memcache where the key is the url. Here's a sample nginx setup:

```
location / {
    if ($request_method = GET)
    {
                    set $memcached_key some_prefix:$request_uri;
                    memcached_pass  localhost:11211;
                    error_page 404 =200 @fallback;
    }

    default_type text/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}

location @fallback {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}
```